# Opening file in iPhone application - NSFileManager isReadableFileAtPath returning NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {

    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:[url absoluteString]] ) {
            NSLog(@"READABLE!");
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[url absoluteString] toPath:[documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/timecode.xml"] error:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT READABLE!");
        }

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/timecode.xml"]];

        if (fileExists) {
            NSLog(@"THERE!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT THERE!");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when I open a file from the mail app (or any other app, including good reader) into my app, it says it isn't readable. And obviously, the file doesn't exist.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because an URL is not a path.

```
[url absoluteString]
```

looks like

```
file:///var/mobile/XXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/Documents/foo.txt
```

You need to use

```
[url path]
```

instead.

Also, two comments:

```
url != nil && [url isFileURL]
```

is highly superfluous.

```
[url isFileURL]
```

will return `NO` anyway if the URL is `nil` (since messaging `nil` always returns zero).

Two:

```
[documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/timecode.xml"]
```

Don't reinvent the wheel/try to guess the path separator. This line ***should*** be

```
[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timecode.xml"]
```

Comment: @objectiveccoder001 Welcome. Lesson learned: be aware of general things before trying to do any programming.